# Get selected items from a grid in sencha modern

Tags: javascript, extjs

In an application I create the controller needs to do "things with the selected items in a grid".

Now the problem is: any way I try I can't seem to get the selection

To get the grid I simply call:

```
let orderGridComponent = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('ordergrid[itemId=ordergrid]')[0];
```

Which seems to work. Now to get the selection according to the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.dataview.DataView.html#cfg-selection) I could simply do:

```
let selection = orderGridComponent.selection;
```

However the selection is always "null". The grid is defined as:

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.main.OrderGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Grid',
    xtype: 'ordergrid',


    columnLines: true,

    selectable: {
        rows: true,
        cells: false
    },

    requires: [
        'myApp.store.OrderStore'
    ],

    title: 'Order data',

    store: {
        type: 'orders'
    },

    columns: [
    {
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        headerCheckbox: true,
        dataIndex: 'selected'
    }, {
        text: 'Order Nr',
        dataIndex: 'orderNr',
        width: 100,
        flex: 1
    }]
});
```

and used as

```
    {
        xtype: 'ordergrid',
        itemId: 'ordergrid',
    }
```

I've also tried `let selection = orderGridComponent.selected` or `getSelected` and many many variants that seem to be suggested around the internet for other ext versions.

So how to do this for the **modern** 6.5.2 framework?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`grid.getSelection()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.grid.selection.Model.html#method-getSelection) method to get selected record.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ai1)**, I have created a demo using `grid`. I hope it will help you to achieve your requirement.

**Code Snippet**

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'selected'],
    data: [{
        name: 'a',
        email: 'a@abc.com',
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: 'b',
        email: 'b@abc.com',
        selected: false
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    title: 'Get Selection',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    fullscreen: true,
    viewModel: {
        selection: null,
        count: 0
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        selectable: {
            mode: 'multi',
            checkbox: true
        },
        store: store,
        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
            text: 'Email',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'email'
        }],
        height: 200,
        listeners: {
            selectionchange: function (grid, re) {
                var selection = grid.getSelections(),
                    data = null,
                    vm = grid.up('panel').getViewModel();

                if (!Ext.isEmpty(selection)) {
                    data = selection.map(rec => {
                        return rec.get('name')
                    }).join(',');
                }
                vm.set('selection', data);
            }
        }
    }],
    bbar: ['->', {
        xtype: 'label',
        bind: {
            html: 'seleted user name is <b>{selection}</b>'
        }
    }]
})
```